# Spyder on Anaconda crashes with Segmentation fault error on Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, anaconda

I have a fresh installation of Linux Mint 19 and a fresh installation of Anaconda 3. All conda commands work perfectly, but when I try to open Spyder, I get the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

My python `sys.path` output is:

```
['', '/home/[USERNAME]/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip', 
 '/home/[USERNAME]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6', 
 '/home/[USERNAME]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
 '/home/[USERNAME]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I uninstalled the latest Anaconda release (5.2) and downgraded to Anaconda 5.0. Now everything works just fine. Probably something is wrong with Mint 19, because Anaconda 5.2 works just fine on my High Sierra Mac.